# ¿Problemas con acentos y caracteres en JSON?

Tags: php, android, json

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android que obtiene datos de un JSON que luce asi

```
[{
"title": "Titulo",
"image": "Imagen url",
"op": "op",
"autor": "Autor",
"fecha": "Noviembre 15, 2016",
"nota":  "ejemplo de nota"
}]
```

El problema es que en mi aplicación los acentos y las "ñ" aparecen con un carácter raro con un signo de interrogación, y estoy casi seguro que el problema esta en el json, como lo soluciono?

Comment: Es importante agregues tu código para revisar como obtienes el .JSON, saludos.

Comment: Sinceramente falta código. Luce asi donde? como has generado el json?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que poner `utf-8` en el `Content-Type` al llamar el metodo.

Por ejemplo:

```
HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpurlconnection.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías incluir también el utf8_encode

- EJEMPLO1:
- $text='Opción';
- $var= utf8_encode($text);
- echo $var;

o también podrías usar iconv

- EJEMPLO2:
- $text='Opción';
- $var=iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', ($text));
- echo $var;

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar que tu base de datos este configurada en `UTF-8` y tambien el archivo donde haces los inserts a tu DB tambien este configurado de esa manera.

Cuando envies la data de tu html o php a tu base de datos utiliza `utf8_encode` y cuando la recibas `utf8_decode`

Comment: No estoy usando base de datos simplemente modifico el json para agregar o actualizar contenido, y el archivo luce exactamente como en el ejemplo no tiene funciones ni nada.

Comment: Con el editor de texto que estes trabajando guarda el archivo en utf8 y agrega a tu archivo `header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta opción:

```
json_encode(
$data,
JSON_HEX_AMP |
JSON_HEX_QUOT |
JSON_HEX_APOS |
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |
JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
);
```

Eso te ayudara, puedes leer la información sobre esto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php)

También te recomiendo que uses esta meta etiqueta:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Es importante definas como obtienes los valores de tu archivo .JSON, debes definir que tipo de encoding tiene el archivo.

Por ejemplo si descargas el archivo creado con enconding `"UTF-8"` puedes definir:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

---

Una opción tal vez la más sencilla es que al obtener tu cadena que contiene caracteres que pertenecen a otra codificación, los codifiques mediante [**URLEncoder.encode()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) :

```
try {
            String cadenaCodificada = URLEncoder.encode(myCadenaCaracteres, "UTF8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```